# Is it possible to have a list of pointers to member functions of one class as a member in another class where these functions will be called?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, stdlist

Let's say we have a class `A`, which has several setter functions with the identical function signature, like the following code:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    void setter1(int whatever)
    {
        // set Something ...
    }
    
    void setter2(int whatever)
    {
        // set Something ...
    }
    
    void setter3(int whatever)
    {
        // set Something ...
    }
};
```

Another class `B` has an object of class `A`. Another class `C` has an object of `B`. In `C`, I try to declare the list of function pointers of `A` and try to call them through `B`'s object.

Following is the example how I called:

```cpp
class B
{
public:
    A objectA;
};
    
class C
{
    C()
    {
        for (auto fnc: fncList)
        {
            someFunc();
        }
    }
    
    void someFunc()
    {
        auto setterFnc = fncList .front();
        fncList.pop_front();
        objectB.objectA. // --> here I can't find the right syntax to call the function;
    } 

    std::list<void (A::*)(int)> fncList = {&A::setter1, &A::setter2, A::setter2};
};
```

Is there any other way to declare the pointer-to-function list so that I can use it from any function of the class `A` through its object in `B` from `C`?

Comment: yes. it is possible.

Comment: did you try anything? If not, go ahead. Its not obvious what issues you encountered unless you tell us and show a [mcve] of your code

Comment: please make an actual attempt to compile some code and post that code and the compiler error message. The code you did post wont "work" because of missing `;` and other errors unrelated to your question

Comment: compiles just fine here https://godbolt.org/z/GYhKT966s. My guess is that your mistake is in how you call the methods. How do you call them? What is the error?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I have posted an example code of what I tried.

Comment: whatever you did wrong is not in the code in the question. The code you did post is fine https://godbolt.org/z/GYhKT966s

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I've updated the code and tried to explain where I have the problem.

Comment: @the_naive See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77453841/12002570) which shows the correct syntax for using `fncList` to call each of the setter. You can modify the program according to your needs after you understand the syntax shown there. As shown in that answer either use `std::invoke` or `(object.*ptr)(someInt)` syntax.

Comment: you could have said already initially that you don't know how to call the method, the actual issue is not whether it is possible or to find a replacement for the list, just saying.

Comment: @the_naive You're welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Somewhere inside one of the functions from class B, all these functions of class A will be called one by one.

Yes it is possible as shown below. You have to have an object or a pointer to an object of your class type for calling the member functions using a pointer to those member functions.

##### C++17

Here you can use [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) to use the pointer to member function to make the code *more readable*.

```
#include <functional> 
#include <list>
struct A
{

    void setter1(int whatever){}
    void setter2(int whatever){}
    void setter3(int whatever){}

};
struct B
{
   std::list<void (A::*)(int)> fncList = {&A::setter1, &A::setter2, &A::setter3};
   //lets add a ctor
   B( A &a, int i)
   {
          for(auto ptr: fncList)
          {
                std::invoke(ptr, a, i);  //calls each of the setter
          }
         
   }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TYqcT8esd)

---

##### Prior C++17

Here we replace the call `std::invoke(ptr, a, i)` with:

```
(a.*ptr)(i);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TqY6Gqa8h)

Comment: Thanks for the syntax. I just realized, that in my actual code we are using a shared pointer to the object whose function pointers I'm trying to call. I tried the syntax.

`mSystem->getObject()->(*fncPointer)(10);`

But it's giving the error `expected a member name`. Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: @the_naive Then the correct syntax would be `((*(mSystem->getObject())).*fncPointer)(10);`. See [working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dxvrTKKGj) where I've added a member function `getObject` and used it like you want.

Comment: @user12002570 If `getObject()` returns an object *pointer*, cleaner syntax would be to use the `->*` operator instead of the `*` and `.*` operators, eg: `(mSystem->getObject()->*fncPointer)(10);` If `getObject()` returns a *smart* pointer, as in your example, then you can access the raw pointer before applying `->*`, eg: `(mSystem->getObject().get()->*fncPointer)(10);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah even better(if OP have C++17) `std::invoke(fncPointer, mSystem->getObject(), 10);`. Btw when writing the last comment I thought about using `->*` but for some reason(most probably because `getObject` is not in the original question and comments are  not so canonical) so I thought I would skip it. If I were writing it in answer, I would've definitely written it using `->*`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. The syntax is gross though.

```
static constexpr void (A::* const setters_of_a[])(int)
```

This declares a core constant array `setters_of_a` of pointers-to-member to `A` of type function taking an `int` and returning `void`.

```
(a.*setter)(42);
```

This calls the member-function referenced by pointer-to-member `setter` on object `a`.

```
#include <iostream>
struct A
{
    void f(int) { std::cout << "A::f()\n";}
    void g(int) { std::cout << "A::g()\n";}
};

struct B
{
    A a;
    static constexpr void (A::* const setters_of_a[])(int) = { &A::f, &A::g };
    void set_a()
    {
        for (auto setter : setters_of_a) {
            (a.*setter)(42);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.set_a();
}
```

[Demo on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/a6e18G6bY)